# auto-capitalise the output of a newcommand

Tags: macros, capitalization

How can I create a `newcommand` that automictically capitalises the first letter, when the command is used after a full stop (or question mark, exclamation mark, etc.)?

```
\newcommand{\tinycommand}{tiny command}
```

The desired input:

```
This is some text and a \tinycommand. This is some text. \tinycommand.
```

The desired result:

This is some text and a tiny command. This is some text. Tiny command.

Comment: You can not use `_` in command names/

Comment: Either `stringstrings` or `titlecaps` packages may give you some tools to work with.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes; A search for `titlecaps` on CTAN gives nill results. A link to more info, please.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : thanks. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Johan_E  The package was just uploaded last week.  Perhaps it is not yet installed at CTAN.

Comment: @Johan_E `titlecaps` _is_ on ctan: `http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlecaps/` -- it ought to have stabilised by now -- where were you looking (and when)?

Comment: @wasteofspace: I went to `http://ctan.org/` and entered (copy-paste'd) `titlecaps` in the search-box at the top and pressed enter (i.e. the search button). This is what I usually do when someone mentions a package I don’t know about.

Comment: There was a multi-month long corruption in the CTAN intall software that left `titlecaps` unsearchable in their database.  It has been fixed.  The package is at http://ctan.org/pkg/titlecaps

Comment: You have to issue `\frenchspacing` *after* you redefine it! Please, remove the edits.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\tinycommand}{\hmm{t}iny command}

\newcommand\hmm[1]{\ifnum\ifhmode\spacefactor\else2000\fi>1000 \uppercase{#1}\else#1\fi}

\begin{document}

The desired input:

This is some text and a \tinycommand. This is some text. \tinycommand.

\end{document}
```

If you use `\frenchspacing` then you would need

```
\def\frenchspacing{\sfcode`\.1001 \sfcode`\?1001 \sfcode`\!1001
  \sfcode`\:1001 \sfcode`\;1001 \sfcode`\,1001 }
```

So that end of sentence is flagged but the change of spacing won't be noticeable.

---

csquotes has its own french spacing values, from `csquotes.sty`

```
\def\csq@setfrcodes{%
  \ifnum\sfcode`\A=\@m
  \else
    \csq@setazcodes
  \fi
  \sfcode`\,=1003
  \sfcode`\;=1004
  \sfcode`\:=1005
  \sfcode`\.=1006
  \sfcode`\!=1007
  \sfcode`\?=1008
}
```

so a value of greater than 1005 is end of sentence, so you just need to adjust the values

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
   % \def\frenchspacing{\sfcode`\.1001 \sfcode`\?1001 \sfcode`\!1001 \sfcode`\:1000 \sfcode`\;1000 \sfcode`\,1000 }  % autocapitalise auch mit frenchspacing
\frenchspacing                  % remove extra space after punctuation
\newcommand{\tinycommand}{\hmm{t}iny command}

\newcommand\hmm[1]{\ifnum\ifhmode\spacefactor\else2000\fi>1005 \uppercase{#1}\else#1\fi}

\begin{document}

The desired input:

This is some text and a \tinycommand. This is some text. \tinycommand. And, \tinycommand. 
And; \tinycommand.
\textquote{And;} \tinycommand.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice “hack”... But it doesn’t work with `\frenchspacing`...

Comment: @Johan_E It would work if you used almost frenchspacing that set the spacefactor codes to 1001 which will not make a visible difference to the space but would enable end of sentence to be triggered.

Comment: @Johan_E code updated for frenchspacing case

Comment: @David Carlisle: `\hbox{\tinicommand.}`?

Comment: @g.kov that wouldn't work:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : what about `\footnote{\tinicommand}`? Is there any way to get that working?

Comment: @ClintEastwood  \makeatletter
\let\old@footnotetext\@footnotetext
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\old@footnotetext{\spacefactor1001 #1}}
\makeatother

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : sorry that I have to come back to this again, but it does not seem to work with comma: `And, \tinycommand.` (irrespective of whether or not `frenchspacing` is activated. I use `frenchspacing`, btw.).

Comment: @ClintEastwood `\sfcode\`\:1001 \sfcode\`\;1001 \sfcode\`\,1001 ` should be `\sfcode\`\:1000 \sfcode\`\;1000 \sfcode\`\,1000 ` as those ones are not end of sentence (if that does the right thing I'll update the answer)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I just found out that your original solution works, but that it does **not** work in my document when I have us `\usepackage{fmtcount}`. If I *don't* use `fmtcount` by deleting the line, it works. Any idea as to why?

Comment: @ClintEastwood I just looked at the source of `fmtcount` (which I didn't know) and see nothing, but the original code treated `,` as end of sentence so wasn't really correct. If you can make a MWE with and without fmtcount and edit in to your question ping me here and I'll look.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle for your help. See updated question with MWEs.

Comment: @ClintEastwood I see egreg already pointed to the error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I have a new question for you, if you want. I updated my question above.

Comment: @ClintEastwood it's better to ask a new question as a new question rather than make substantial edits to an old one, but I updated the answer this time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I am currently unable to submit an MWE but I experience a strange behaviour. Sometimes the command `\tinycommand` gets me a capitalised letter after a dot, and sometimes not. I could not find out why nor what the difference between the two cases is. I know that without an MWE no one can look into the matter. I just wanted to report. I have no clue.